# How to saving salt

Tags: express, hash, sequelize.js, salt

maybe, in the signup process,
( I using express.js, MySQL, Sequelize )

1. get ID and PW at Front-end
2. saving ID in DB
3. hashing the pw with salt
4. save hashed pw in DB

And,,,
can I use salt used before?

when some user log-in this server,
their PW will be hashing and compair with DB data.
but salt is just random..
so I wanna save salt value!

Comment: How are you hashing the password? Most of the tools I've used (e.g. bcrypt) include the salt in their output already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `bcrypt`

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(12)
// Continue whatever user saving happens here with salt
```

Other libraries may also have these functions, generate a salt, use it as the parameter of hashing

Comment: can I get such user's salt value? in that way?

Comment: Through the salt variable. See how `const salt` defines a salt variable? That will be the salt you use for the user